# MVVM WPF save and load user settings design pattern

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am looking for a good tutorial / explanation that shows where and how to implement settings in a **MVVM** WPF application.  I understand .net has built-in support for settings but is this typically used for medium to larger size applications?  What are the alternatives?

I am thinking of storing many user settings such as window size, grid column size, font size, font, etc...

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in settings file is a good place to store common things like window size, theme, etc... (Stuff the user does not enter themselves... ambient state) but for more advanced settings that the user can customize, I would rather build my own... This gives me better control over how and where it gets stored! Also check out [this](http://rudigroblerwp.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/building-openpos-part-9-%E2%80%93-settings-and-notifications/) article for an example of a medium sized MVVM app using the settings file!

Comment: thanks for the comment and link.  I like how the properties bind directly to the xaml in the example.  I did not find a clear design pattern to implement the custom settings file.  Should the settings file be a singleton? and where is the file generally kept etc...

Comment: As @ArsenMkrt says, the article has now moved to http://rudigroblerwp.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/building-openpos-part-9-%E2%80%93-settings-and-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the **Writer** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to use the Settings in a WPF MVVM application.

This approach should be sufficient for the properties you like to store.

Comment: Thank for the link, I have looked at waf before - looks great but the settings aspect of the sample did not clearly standout to me.